# How is a c_ptr assigned in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, fortran2003

Given a Fortran derived type with a field which is a c_ptr (from iso_c_binding) and two variables A and B of said type, how is the assignment A = B defined? If the pointers were fortran pointers, they would in effect be dereferenced during the assignment. Is the same true for the c_ptr?

```
USE, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
...
type all_mine
    real    :: E
    type(c_ptr) :: ptr_to_some_c
end type all_mine
...
type(all_mine)  :: A, B
...
A = B   ! What happens here?
```

Comment: If the `pointer_to_some_c` component was a Fortran pointer component, then it would not be dereferenced when the derived type holding the component was assigned.

Answer (score 2):

The C address stored inside the C_PTR derived type object is not dereferenced as a (top level) Fortran pointer would.  The C address inside the right hand side object is assigned to the left hand side object.

(Its more akin to Fortran non-polymorphic scalar pointer assignment.)

Conceptually it is as if the C_PTR type had only non-allocatable, non-pointer components and they were assigned across by the rules of intrinsic assignment.